# Can't detect second monitor after fglrx install

Tags: ati, intel-graphics, fglrx, hybrid-graphics, multiple-monitors

I have two monitor (one connected to the AMD GPU's HDMI port and one connected to the integrated Intel's HDMI port). After the installation of AMD Crymson, the second monitor is no more available in the system configuration menu.
How can I use both monitor (with different drivers eventually)?